# Read the text from PDF file which is inside a box using C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm just facing a problem in fetching the data from a PDF file using C#.

Please have a look at the image below,
[image: My PDF File]

In the above image i'll pass the parameter value as "Customre Name"(The text in blue color).

Once i find that perticular text in the PDF file then i need to fetch related information of that "Customer Name".

I need the values like "See Data" and the text which is inside the Box.

I'm successfully fetching the value "See Data" but I'm failing to fetch the text which is inside the box, because the text inside the box is of variable number of lines, it may be in single line or multi line like 2, 3, 4 lines.

So for I'm trying in this way,

I fetch the data of a pdf file using iTextSharp, and I'll store the data of that page into line by line manner, in the line where I find "Customer Name" i'll add 1+ and i'll fetch the "See Data" Value then while fetching the value in the text box i don't know how many lines it will be and failed to do so.

So can any one of you help me in fetching the value of that text box.

Please let me know if you confused with my question.

Thanking you in advance,

Dada.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question? I would propose trying to recognize the rectangle, but for that one has to know how that rectangle is drawn internally.

Comment: @mkl that PDF file is very confidential one which i'm not able to share with you, and the thing is that PDF file came from client and don't know exactly how that box has been drawn and what they used to draw it.

Comment: If you can neither share the PDF nor explain the way it internally is generating certain appearances, thee is not enough information to help (unless going for lucky shots).